# Tomcat - SharedLoader - Heap increased

Tags: memory-management, jvm, shared-libraries, heap-memory, tomcat9

I have a Tomcat 9.0.35 and I've changed some libs from webapps web-inf folder to Tomcat SharedFolder and the attribute "delegate" was true(so Tomcat first looks at Common, after Shared and after that Webapps). So webapps get smaller and LIB folder had new files.

At the scenario of web-inf, the heap was 800mb and startup was done in 100ms
At the scenario of SharedFolder, the heap increased to 1,1GB when I expected to decrease but startup decreased to 75ms.

I'm anxious to know why heap increased if webapps have decreased and my goal was also consume less memory.

Could anyone help me to understand it? Is that a problem?

[EDIT]
Below we have the dominator tree with webinf jars
[image: Dominator tree with webinf jars]

And after moving jars to shared lib, here's dominator tree
[image: Dominator tree with jars at shared folder]

I can't get the cause of this changes, why Finalizer growed so much...

Answer (score 0):

After seeing [this video](https://vimeo.com/21356498), I've searched Dominator Tree and Finalizer Statistics and saw that ZipFileInputStream class was too much referenced. That class overrides "finalize" method and because of this, it's out of Garbage Collector cycle. Again, looking for child
nodes of ZipFileInputStream, I've found the libraries I've added to shared loader